# Remove elements on based on window size

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to remove a div element on mobile devices only (based on window size).

The element is an advertisement and by using CSS (display:none) is still registered  on mobile devices even though the ad does not show (is just hidden), and this is making a fake impression.

My ads are inserted trough Wordpress theme options (where the ad code itself is added). And from the function I get the code in the page.

```
<div class="topad">
    <div class="adh" id="adbox"><?php echo get_option('amn_topad'); ?></div>
</div>
```

I probably have the right code for this but it may be placed in the wrong place.
I have used in the header.php (where the div is located):

```
if ($(window).width() < 700) {
  $('.topad').remove();
}
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($(window).width() < 700) {
  $('.topad').remove();
}
});
```

I have also tried to make a custom.js with the same codes as before and add to functions.php

```
function my_scripts_method() {
   wp_register_script('custom_script',
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js',
   array('jquery'),
   '1.0' );
  wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
  }
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

I don't know if it's possible but a simpler and efficient way would be to prevent the div to appear by inserting an "if" directly in element

```
<div class="adh" id="adbox"><?php if() {echo get_option('amn_topad');} ?></div>
```

Comment: What if I'm a user with a browser at 710, and then i resize to 650, and then resize to 730?

Comment: My point is, other than (potentially) "it's in the DOM and I don't like it being there", what problem are you trying to solve that having a media query that simply hides it doesn't solve?

Comment: @Taplar The website is responsive so it should not be a problem. But it doesn't matter anyway since you accessed the page with 710, it will show, if you resize, it will disappear

Comment: It will not show if I resize to 650, and then resize to 730, if your javascript logic removes it from the dom.

Comment: @Taplar No, it doesn't solve, because is just hiding the element, so it's still here, but the user can't see it

Comment: And?  What's the problem?

Comment: @Taplar The ad is registered as being seen and generate a fake impression and  lowers the click through rate, also doubles the adverts page views

Comment: Use CSS like the answer suggests.

Comment: i agree with everyone here that this should be solved with css as suggested. but just to complete:  you could use browser detection and supress the rendering completely for cellphones. look for "server side browser detection". eg http://mobiledetect.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the element completely is not the way that the industry is going - you might want to do that still, but please consider the counter-arguments:

- The element won't be showing back if the screen gets resized up over the threshold
- To remove the element after the user resizes down under the threshold, you must detect this behavior with JS, which complexifies the code
- The element might be useful to other parts of your code

The way that is widely adopted in the industry to change display based on size width is to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Here's a quick demo to show/hide elements based on the screen size (over or under 700px) - resize your window to make it work!

```css
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  /* mobile CSS: hide .desktop div */
  .desktop {
    display: none
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  /* desktop CSS: hide .mobile div */
  .mobile {
    display: none
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile">
  I appear only on mobile devices! (screen width less than 700)
</div>
<div class="desktop">
  I appear only on desktop devices! (screen width over 700)
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Remove JavaScript from the equation and let CSS do its thing.

Comment: I'm already using CSS, but I don't think this is the fair solution for anyone, because the ad is loaded but not seen. The advertiser pays for views that are are not there and I'm also loosing potential clickers

Comment: If you remove the ad on the client side, the ad is also loaded, because you call `remove` *after* it's being loaded in the DOM.

Comment: @NinoFiliu That's true, thanks for a more suitable answer